# swift - Custom Annotation Offset in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have the following annotation with a callout in the form of a xib file that looks like this:

[Current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M2Ss.png)

I would like to know how to offset the annotation callout so that the origin of the annotation callout is not at the point of the annotation itself, but offset by 10 points on the y axis, so it would be a little bit above the annotation. Is there a way to do this?

Can you help me achieve this? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Still looking for the solution.

Comment: Try to make that bottom 10px content with alpha set to 0.

Comment: That is actually a very creative solution!

Comment: I cannot use this however because I would prefer if my annotation dropped shadow.

Comment: @CtiborŠebák
Try create a view (B) inside your view (A) then make the shadow and everything u want inside the inner view (B) and make the bg color of main view (A) Default then you have an offset equal to space between A and B.

Comment: Now, the main view (A) is just a container with transparent color !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my case, it was just a question of setting the origin of the custom annotationView that I creted from a xib file.

Like so:

`newCustomCalloutView.frame.origin.y -= newCustomCalloutView.frame.height + 3`

The important part is the `+ 3` in the line above.

Answer (score 0):

I set it in swift code like this:

```
class CarAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            guard let carAnnotation = newValue as? CarAnnotation else { return }
            self.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

The important line is:

```
self.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything for me, I tried to put it in various places where the annotation gets initialized, including the place in my custom annotation view class that you did in your code example. No idea why.